# Does somebody know how can I get a hashtag data from Facebook(FB) ,it is impossible or not?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, hashtag, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Is it impossible to get the hashtag data from FB graph with V2 , or other ways or methods to do it ,hopefully this question is not very hard,  Thank you for your patience if you have read my question in the end.

> PS: For FB graph V2.* I am afraid it was provided HASHTAG data's
>   ,however Can I get it by paying money ??? thanks again

**so now, I knew FB can not offer any resources to public place.**

Comment: I don't know why this question that has gotten a negative point , hopefully some one can tell me how to do ,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since v2.0 it's no longer possible to search for public posts, so: No, it's not possible